# WPF spell check only custom dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

Our app works with many languages. I need to be able to specify which language to use for each textbox. That seems to be fine; I can just do this:

```xaml
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
         Language="en-gb"/>
```

Of course this requires that the user has the appropriate language pack installed. That's not completely horrible (although seems very archaic and restrictive), but the issue is that the Windows 10 `en-gb` dictionary allows "ize" spellings (for some reason?) and our client requires that they stick strictly to "ise" spellings.

So my thought was ok, what if we just include a custom dictionary for each supported language with the app? Seems legit:

```xaml
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
         Language="">
    <SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
        <sys:Uri>dict/en-gb-ise.lex</sys:Uri>
    </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
</TextBox>
```

...except that if the `Language` property is set to something that doesn't exist, spell checking is disabled. Sigh.

How can I specify a custom dictionary for each textbox individually that completely overrides whatever OS-supplied dictionaries exist?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries?view=windowsdesktop-6.0  

<!-- customwords.lex is included as a content file--> <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/customwords.lex</sys:Uri>

Comment: Custom dictionaries are used in addition to the default. They don't replace the default dictionary.

Comment: The "problem" is that British English or Oxford English is officially favoring "-ize" as it is based on the Greek root of the words. You can try to check if there are spelling dictionaries of British English countries that strictly go with the suffix "-ise". Then use this language instead of "en-GB".

Comment: @BionicCode Source? That's an interesting change. As far as choosing another dictionary, well that seems like it will cause more problems than it solves. I honestly just find it surprising that there's no facility to use your own dictionary, or at least have more control.

Comment: @silverfighter Not really sure what the point of that comment is. I already showed in the question that I know how to use a custom dictionary and that custom dictionaries don't appear to solve my problem.

Comment: See the last paragraph of [SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries - Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks). You can implement your own spell checking. It's not difficult. You can render the spell error indicator on the AdornerLayer. In this scenario, you can use the original en-GB dictionary. You only add a behind the scene dictionary with disallowed spellings. This won't be difficult by takes some effort. You would also have to hide the TextBox.GetSpellingError method to add your custom suggestions.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to find some information about that. I'm not sure what you mean about the last paragraph in the Remarks section, though; it doesn't mention anything about implementing your own spell checking as far as I can see (it just says how to enable spell checking on a text box).

Comment: Last paragraph reads: *"All custom dictionaries for that TextBox are used in addition to the default spelling checker"*. Maybe you find a library that offers the features you need.

Comment: @BionicCode But... I'm not sure why you're saying that. I _know_ that's the case. That's the whole point of my question. Plus it sounded like you were saying that that paragraph was related to implementing your own spell checking, so it was just generally a confusing thing to say.

Comment: I really don't understand you. *"Im not sure why you're saying that. I know that's the case. That's the whole point of my question"* - good for you. Your original question leaves a different impression: *"How can I specify a custom dictionary for each textbox individually that completely overrides whatever OS-supplied dictionaries exist?"*. I replied that this is not possible. You then asked for a source of proof. I referenced the last paragraph. That's all. My conclusion was that you need to implement your own spell checking or find a library that already did this and I shared this thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I specify a custom dictionary for each textbox individually that completely overrides whatever OS-supplied dictionaries exist?

I am afraid you cannot disable or override the default dictionary. This is not supported.

As stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), custom dictionaries are only used *in additon* to the default spelling checker.

Comment: `As stated in the docs` Indeed, however that doesn't mean there's not another way to achieve my goal. For instance, a 3rd-party or even custom manually-implemented spell checker?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the place to ask for recommendations for 3rd-party software I am afraid. Of course you could implement your own spell-checker or use a third-party tool but that's not what your question is about, is it?

Comment: _"but that's not what your question is about, is it?"_ My question was "how can I specify a custom dictionary that overrides the default". If the answer is "do it yourself as shown here" or "use this third-party library" then that's exactly what my question was about.

Comment: Then I am afraid it's out of scope of SO.

Comment: I completely disagree. If there's a known solution, whether or not it involves the use of a 3rd-party library, that's exactly in the scope of SO. I'm not new here. My question is clear, focused and not opinion-based. I'm asking if there's a way to replace the stock dictionaries with a custom one. If that answer is "no", then that's the answer, but equally so if the answer is "don't do that, do this".

Comment: Fair enough but "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is likely to lead to opinion-based answers" is what the "closing" dialog says under the "This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline" option. That's what I am referring to.